# Application doen't compile after switching to Maven 3.6.3

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I work with one legacy project and decided to switch CI pipeline from maven 3.6.0 to 3.6.3
Now unfortunately, some tests begin to fail. Nothing in code base was changed at all. But I get errors about invalid database name (derby). I have tried to run code as a standalone application and it compiles and executes good.
here is code

```
/**
 * @param testCase
 * @param databaseType
 * @return
 */
@Override
public Connection createDatabase(Class<?> testCase)
{
  try
  {
    File testDir = new File(TARGET_TESTDB);
    testDir.mkdirs();
    File testdb = new File(testDir, testCase.getName());
    if (testdb.exists())
      deleteDirectory(testdb);
    Class.forName(DERBY_DRIVER);
    String url = "jdbc:derby:" + testdb + ";create=true";
    log.debug("Creating test database {}", url);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url); //ERROR IS HERE
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    return con;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new RuntimeException("Caught exception creating database for test case "
      + testCase.getName(), e);
  }
}
```

and here is stacktrace

```
Test set: com.xxxxxx.yyyyy.sql.ddl.filter.DdlColumnFilterTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.086 sec <<< FAILURE!
com.xxxxxx.yyyyy.sql.ddl.filter.DdlColumnFilterTest  Time elapsed: 62.242 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Caught exception creating database for test case com.xxxxxx.yyyyy.sql.ddl.filter.DdlColumnFilterTest
    at com.navteq.phoenix.test.util.impl.DatabaseTestUtilDerby.createDatabase(DatabaseTestUtilDerby.java:88)
    at com.xxxxxx.yyyyy.sql.ddl.filter.DdlColumnFilterTest.runBeforeClass(DdlColumnFilterTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address: jdbc:derby:target/testdb/com.xxxxxx.yyyyy.sql.ddl.filter.DdlColumnFilterTest;create=true
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:74)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.xxxxxx.yyyyy.test.util.impl.DatabaseTestUtilDerby.createDatabase(DatabaseTestUtilDerby.java:82)
```

**How can I fix that or I should return back to maven 3.6.0?**

Comment: Were you able to run it with Maven 3.6.0? This error doesn't relate to maven upgrade.

Comment: You have a failing test `DdlColumnFilterTest`...unrelated to Maven upgrade as already mentioned by @kann

Comment: Actually, when I switch on maven 3.6.0 - ALL TESTS (include DdlColumnFilterTest)  RUN SUCCESSFULLY

Comment: So when you run it successfully, does derby URL get a different value assigned?

Comment: I would try to fix the actual error instead of going back with Maven versions.